# Checking if two strings are permutations of each other

Tags: java

How to determine if two strings are permutations of each other

Comment: http://n1b-algo.blogspot.com/2009/01/string-permutations.html try to analyze this. It uses recursion to print all the permutations

Comment: i can do the permutation using recursion.but i can't get to compare the 2 strings.that is the problem.can u help me with it?That's why i was asking for the whole code.

Comment: Similar (but not quite a dupe as it is about a different part of the problem): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895625/odd-comparison-problem-in-checking-for-anagram

Comment: can't use sorting.got to use recursion.

Comment: i will have to use recursion or hashmap.second i am new to java.third,the java code will be ported to c++.However,the java code will also be used somewhere else.Enough explanations.Stephen?

Comment: So what prevents you from sorting the characters?

Comment: there are some limitations to that.mainly for speed purposes

Comment: -1 for the numerous questions to "post the codez".

Comment: Just checked how much points you need to be able to vote down: it's 100. So you being able to -1 me for spite is out of the question. But if you were able to do so, I wouldn't care the least.

Answer (score 43):

- Sort the two strings's characters.
- Compare the results to see if they're identical.

**Edit:**

The above method is reasonably efficient - O(n*log(n)) and, as others have shown, very easy to implement using the standard Java API. Even more efficient (but also more work) would be counting and comparing the occurrence of each character, using the char value as index into an array of counts.

I do not thing there is an efficient way to do it recursively. An inefficient way (O(n^2), worse if implemented straightforwardly) is this:

- If both strings consist of one identical character, return true
- Otherwise:

  - remove one character from the first string
  - Look through second string for occurrence of this character
  - If not present, return false
  - Otherwise, remove said character and apply algorithm recursively to the remainders of both strings.

Comment: what about a hash-map?Can u give me code on that regarding this prob?

Comment: A hash map would not be helpful. And I will not do your work for you.

Comment: @Supratim: how do you want to pass the class if you only want the code? You're supposed to write it and if you can't then you will (and should!) fail the class.

Comment: a hash map could be helpful, or even just a 26 element array of int. you can create a histogram of each string and compare those for equality. O(n) runtime but O(n) extra storage.

Comment: i don't recall talking to u--Joachim.

Comment: @jk yeah, I meantioned that option, though I would not assume the input consists only of unaccented latin letters.

Comment: @Supratim People will gladly help you with any specific problems you have getting *your* solution to work. But they will not hand you ready-made code. Joachim is entirely right in what he said. If you want others to do your homework assignments for you, do everyone a favor and drop out of school right away; the net effect will be the same as if you continue like this.

Comment: well mike,have u seen the code not so long ago?however,seems like u guys are positively going to get me back to school.

Comment: the prob is with that code is --how do i get those two strings to compare to each other?

Comment: i pasted a code -mike--check it out.c if u can help me after this.

Comment: Well, you've pasted the code other people wrote in their answers. You have not tried to implement the recursive method I described above.

Comment: really,mike,like i said,u guys are too smart.anyway,thanx for evrything.

Answer (score 35):

To put @Michael Borgwardt's words in to code:

```
public boolean checkAnagram(String str1, String str2) {

    if (str1.length() != str2.length())
      return false;

    char[] a = str1.toCharArray();
    char[] b = str2.toCharArray();

    Arrays.sort(a);
    Arrays.sort(b);

    return Arrays.equals(a, b);
}
```

Comment: There's also Arrays.equals() for the last step. But the idea was not to give readymade code for an obvious homework question.

Comment: @Supratim: what do you think you've been given here? A great suggestion on how to do it *and* the code.

Comment: And someone down-voted me for giving away the full code for a homework question.

Comment: @Amarghosh: I tend to agree that giving full code here is not a good service (didn't downvote, 'though). In this case not even the OP seems to thank you for it.

Comment: @Joachim I see your point - I was rep-whoring to hit 8K ASAP I guess ;)

Comment: Do you mean that your teacher wants you to use recursion in solving this? I am not gonna repeat the mistake of giving away the ready made code for homework again.

Comment: Thanks for specifying all these requirements in question and thanks for being so nice to me even though I couldn't come up with anything you asked for in the question. I'll try to avoid being unhelpful like this in the future. @Joachim You were right.

Comment: @Amarghosh: Just got to see this thread I don't know where I clicked that brought me this thread. Anyways, a suggestion, you might appreciate. 1. As Joachim said, "Its not a good idea to give away the full code, its bad for students". 2. Don't do it in the respect of folks who decided not to give the full code, especially when they are seniors (of course age doesn't matter here, nor repo).

Comment: What's the runtime of this?

Comment: @Jasmine O(1) for strings of different length, O(n * log n) for strings of the same length, due to `Array.sort()`. String.toCharArray()` and `Array.equals()` are both O(n), so the sorting dictates the runtime.

Answer (score 24):

Create a Hashmap with the characters of the first string as keys and the number of occurances as value; then go through the second string and for each character, look up the hash table and decrement the number if it is greater than zero. If you don't find an entry or if it is already 0, the strings are not a permutation of each other. Obviously, the string must have the same length.

Comment: Can u please give me the Javacode using hashmaps for this problem?
Thanx

Comment: Supratim: There is a consensus here at SO that we should not do homework for others. Giving you the code would get me downvoted.

Comment: is it ok?if not what's the prob?

Comment: I think this is the superior approach because it's an O(n) algorithm. Another variant is to create two hash tables (`HashMaps` in Java) from the respective input arrays/strings. Then, we just compare the two hash tables. The built-in `.equals` should work. As hash table comparisons are O(n), this is also O(n), as expected.

Answer (score 7):

Linear Time solution in HashMap. Traverse and put first String in HashMap, keep the count of each character. Traverse second String and if it is already in the hashmap decrease the count by 1. At the end if all character were in the string the value in hashmap will be 0 for each character.

```
public class StringPermutationofEachOther {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

    String s1= "abc";
    String s2 ="bbb";
    System.out.println(perm(s1,s2));
}
    public static boolean perm(String s1, String s2)
    { HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    int count =1;
        if(s1.length()!=s2.length())
        {
            return false;
        }
            for(Character c: s1.toCharArray())
            {
                if(!map.containsKey(c))
                    map.put(c, count);

                else
                    map.put(c, count+1);

            }
            for(Character c: s2.toCharArray())
            {
                if(!map.containsKey(c))
                    return false;

                else
                    map.put(c, count-1);
            }
            for(Character c: map.keySet())
            {
                if(map.get(c)!=0)
                    return false;
            }
        return true;
    }


}
```

Comment: This is incorrect since the count variable is not being reset when traversing the string. When a character is repeated more than twice, the value stored in the map for count becomes incorrect. I've proposed a correction here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43954079/697935

Comment: I don't know if it's updated later but the above code works fine. The count is reseted to 1 every time you call the permutation function. @GustavoGuevara

Answer (score 5):

You can try to use XOR, if one string is a permeation of the other, they should have essentially identical chars. The only difference is just the order of chars. Therefore using XOR trick can help you get rid of the order and focus only on the chars.

```
public static boolean isPermutation(String s1, String s2){
    if (s1.length() != s2.length()) return false;
    int checker = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < s1.length();i++ ){
        checker ^= s1.charAt(i) ^ s2.charAt(i);
    }

    return checker == 0;
}
```

Comment: Nope! String s1 = "aabcd"; String s2 = "bcddd"; It returns true ! Because xor will eliminate even number of appearance, your solution will be correct if all characters are unique.

Comment: ["AB", "12"] is another such case that could give trouble

Comment: This solution will only work if both of the String is the same. But, then you directly call the equals function.

Answer (score 4):

1. Sort the 2 strings by characters and compare if they're the same (O(n log n) time, O(n) space), *or*
2. Tally the character frequency of the 2 strings and compare if they're the same (O(n) time, O(n) space).

Comment: Actually, the space required is `O(1)` in the second case - 2**16 ints.

Comment: That's a bad O(1) ;) And I could use a hash table.

Comment: In the worst case a hash table is significantly more that 2**16 words.  But yes, a hash table would be better in typical cases and also `O(1)` in space / time.  BTW - you haven't fixed the error yet ...

Comment: For the first, wouldn't it be O(n + log n) time? i.e. just O(n)?

Comment: heap sort can perform an in-place sorting and technically that would mean space complexity of `O(1)`

Comment: @Damiox yes, only if you want to destroy the content of the strings.

Comment: @kennytm yep, that's true

Answer (score 2):

You might take a look at [String.toCharArray](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()) and  [Arrays.sort](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(char[]))

Comment: can't use sorting.got to use hash maps or recursion.can u help me with that?

Comment: @Supratim: there are already other answers that make use of a hashmap or recursion. What's wrong with them?

Comment: i need the code.i am new to java.and i will port the code to c++.The java code i need.

Answer (score 2):

First you check the lengths (`n`), if they are not same, they cannot be permutations of each other. Now create two `HashMap<Character, Integer>`. Iterate over each string and put the number of times each character occur in the string. E.g. if the string is aaaaa, the map will have just one element with key a and value 5. Now check if the two maps are identical. This is an `O(n)` algorithm.

EDIT with code snippet :

```
boolean checkPermutation(String str1, String str2) {

char[] chars1 = str1.toCharArray();
char[] chars2 = str2.toCharArray();

Map<Character, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
Map<Character, Integer> map2 = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

for (char c : chars1) {
   int occ = 1;
   if (map1.containsKey(c) {
       occ = map1.get(c);
       occ++;
   }
   map1.put(c, occ);
}

// now do the same for chars2 and map2

if (map1.size() != map2.size()) {
   return false;
}
for (char c : map1.keySet()) {

    if (!map2.containsKey(c) || map1.get(c) != map2.get(c)) {
        return false;
    }
}

return true;
}
```

Comment: Is a homework! The idea is that you solve it by yourself, in order to learn.

Comment: nice,but i cannot get the code to work,and where is the user input for the strings?

Comment: i think there is also some problem with the method declaration.

Comment: ok,2 problems with this code--how do i give the input? & The strings str1 and str2 are immutable.so they are constant.what can be done?

Comment: I don't why you are so hung up on the input part? Somebody has already give a solution below using BufferedReader : 

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

Comment: if u implement that using bufferred reader with this code u will understnd what i am talking about.why don't u have a go?and how about making the strings mutable.

Comment: Personally, I consider any Java answer bunk unless they make the strings mutable.  What good is an answer if they don't attempt to completely restructure the underlying language at the same time?

Comment: @fastcodejava For the last step of checking for equality, can't we just do `map1.equals(map2)`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on a Java library that should simplify your task. You can [re-implement this algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131997/checking-if-two-strings-are-permutations-of-each-other/2132035#2132035) using only two method calls:

```
boolean arePermutationsOfSameString(String s1, String s2) {
    s1 = $(s1).sort().join(); 
    s2 = $(s2).sort().join();
    return s1.equals(s2);
}
```

### testcase

```
@Test
public void stringPermutationCheck() {
    // true cases
    assertThat(arePermutationsOfSameString("abc", "acb"), is(true));
    assertThat(arePermutationsOfSameString("bac", "bca"), is(true));
    assertThat(arePermutationsOfSameString("cab", "cba"), is(true));

    // false cases
    assertThat(arePermutationsOfSameString("cab", "acba"), is(false));
    assertThat(arePermutationsOfSameString("cab", "acbb"), is(false));

    // corner cases
    assertThat(arePermutationsOfSameString("", ""), is(true));
    assertThat(arePermutationsOfSameString("", null), is(true));
    assertThat(arePermutationsOfSameString(null, ""), is(true));
    assertThat(arePermutationsOfSameString(null, null), is(true));
}
```

### PS

In the case you can clone the [souces at bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org/dfa/dollar/wiki/Home).

Comment: nice,but can u give me complete code of the same problem using hash--map?Thanx anyway.

Comment: why a hash-map? imho it is the wrong data structure for this problem

Comment: becoz i have to use hash map.otherwise the arrays.sort was the best method.

Comment: $(s1).sort() does exactly Arrays.sort() internally

Comment: thtat's the prob,can't use sorting.Have to do it some other way--recursion or hash-map will do.can u plz give me completed java code on this one?thanx.

Answer (score 1):

I did this, and it works well and quickly:

```
public static boolean isPermutation(String str1, String str2)
{
    char[] x = str1.toCharArray();
    char[] y = str2.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(x);
    Arrays.sort(y);
    if(Arrays.equals(x, y))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean isPermutationOfOther(String str, String other){
    if(str == null || other == null)
        return false;
    if(str.length() != other.length())
        return false;

    Map<Character, Integer> characterCount = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        int count = 1;
        if(characterCount.containsKey(c)){
            int k = characterCount.get(c);
            count = count+k;
        }

        characterCount.put(c, count);

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < other.length(); i++) {
        char c = other.charAt(i);
        if(!characterCount.containsKey(c)){
            return false;
        }

        int count = characterCount.get(c);
        if(count == 1){
            characterCount.remove(c);
        }else{
            characterCount.put(c, --count);
        }
    }

    return characterCount.isEmpty();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Variation on other approaches but this one uses 2 int arrays to track the chars, no sorting, and you only need to do 1 for loop over the strings.  The for loop I do over the int arrays to test the permutation is a constant, hence not part of N.

Memory is constant.

O(N) run time.

```
// run time N, no sorting, assume 256 ASCII char set
public static boolean isPermutation(String v1, String v2) {

    int length1 = v1.length();
    int length2 = v2.length();
    if (length1 != length2)
        return false;

    int s1[] = new int[256];
    int s2[] = new int[256];

    for (int i = 0; i < length1; ++i) {
        int charValue1 = v1.charAt(i);
        int charValue2 = v2.charAt(i);
        ++s1[charValue1];
        ++s2[charValue2];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length; ++i) {

        if (s1[i] != s2[i])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Unit Tests

```
@Test
public void testIsPermutation_Not() {
    assertFalse(Question3.isPermutation("abc", "bbb"));
}

@Test
public void testIsPermutation_Yes() {
    assertTrue(Question3.isPermutation("abc", "cba"));
    assertTrue(Question3.isPermutation("abcabcabcabc", "cbacbacbacba"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If we do the initial length check, to determine if the two strings are of the same length or not,

```
    public boolean checkIfPermutation(String str1, String str2) {
      if(str1.length()!=str2.length()){
        return false;
      }
      int str1_sum = getSumOfChars(str1);
      int str2_sum = getSumOfChars(str2);
      if (str1_sum == str2_sum) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
}

public int getSumOfChars(String str){
      int sum = 0; 
      for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        sum += str.charAt(i);
      }
      return sum;
}
```

Comment: `checkIfPermutation("abc", "bbb")` returns `true`

Answer (score 0):

The obligatory [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) one-liner:

```
boolean isAnagram(String s1, String s2) {
    return ImmutableMultiset.copyOf(Chars.asList(s1.toCharArray())).equals(ImmutableMultiset.copyOf(Chars.asList(s2.toCharArray())));
}
```

(Just for fun.  I don't recommend submitting this for your assignment.)

Answer (score 0):

As you requested, here's a complete solution using recursion.
Now all you have to do is:

1. Figure out what language this is
2. Translate it to Java.

Good luck :-)

```
proc isAnagram(s1, s2);
  return {s1, s2} = {''} or
         (s2 /= '' and
          (exists c = s1(i) |
                  s2(1) = c and
                  isAnagram(s1(1..i-1) + s1(i+1..), s2(2..))));
end isAnagram;
```

Comment: proc-end is also there in eye-OS

Comment: Poor syntax highlighter got crazy)

Comment: Not the most efficient method though.

Comment: There is also a HP 9000 computers assembler directive like this.However i don't think it is that.

Comment: I think it is ruby.Well finnw?

Comment: You're obviously not going to guess it.  It's SETL.

Comment: never used it,so how am i supposed to know?

Comment: however,surprised that u still using SETL instead of ProSet,finnw

Comment: I am not aware of any public release of ProSet

Answer (score 0):

I did  it using  C#

```
bool Arepermutations(string string1, string string2)
        {
            char[] str1 = string1.ToCharArray();
            char[] str2 = string2.ToCharArray();
            if (str1.Length !=str2.Length)
              return false; 
            Array.Sort(str1); 
            Array.Sort(str2);
            if (str1.Where((t, i) => t!= str2[i]).Any())
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true; 

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean permitation(String s,String t){
      if(s.length() != t.length()){
          return false;
          }

       int[] letters = new int[256];//Assumes that the character set is ASCII
       char[] s_array = s.toCharArray();

       for(char c:s_array){         /////count number of each char in s
             letters[c]++;
        }
       for(int i=0;i<t.length();i++){
             int c = (int)t.charAt(i);
             if(--letters[c]<0){
                  return false;
             }
        }
        return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
             import java.io.*;
                      public class permute 
                    {
                              public static String sort(String s)
                              {
                                     char[] str = s.toCharArray();
                                    java.util.Arrays.sort(str);
                                    return new String(str);
                              }
                      public static boolean permutation(String s,String t)
                     {
                            if(s.length()!=t.length())
                           {
                                   return false;
                           }
                                   return sort(s).equals(sort(t));
                     }
    public static void main(String[] args)            throws IOException
    {
           BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
           String string = null;
           boolean x=true;
           System.out.println("Input String:");
           string = bf.readLine();
           System.out.println("Input another String:");
           String result = bf.readLine();
           String resultant = sort(string);
           if(x==permutation(result,resultant))
           {
                    System.out.println("String"+" "+"("+result+")"+"is a permutation of String"+" "+"("+string+")");
           }
           else
           {
                    System.out.println("Sorry No anagram found");
           }       
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TwoStrgPermutation {

public int checkForUnique(String s1, String s2)
{
    int[] array1 = new int[256];
    int[] array2 = new int[256];

    array1 = arrayStringCounter(array1,s1);
    array2 = arrayStringCounter(array2,s2);

    if(Arrays.equals(array1, array2))
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}

public int[] arrayStringCounter(int[] array,String s)
{
    int val;
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
    {
        val = (int)s.charAt(i);
        array[val]++;
    }

    return array;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
    TwoStrgPermutation obj = new TwoStrgPermutation();
    try {
        String string1 = br.readLine();
        String string2 = br.readLine();

        int len1 = string1.length();
        int len2 = string2.length();

        if(len1==len2)
        {
            int result = obj.checkForUnique(string1,string2);
            if (result == 0){
                System.out.println("yes it is a permutation");
            }
            else if (result >0)
            {
                System.out.println("no it is not");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("no it is not");
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>>def isPermutation = lambda x, y: set([i for i in x]) == set([j for j in x])
>>>isPermutation("rasp", "spar")
>>>True
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an O(N) solution, in which N is the length of the shorter string.
It has a disadvantage, which is that only ASCII characters are acceptable.
If we want better applicability, we may substitute a hash table for the `int charNums[]`.
But it also means C wouldn't be a good choice, coz' there is no standard hash table implementation for C.

```
int is_permutation(char *s1, char *s2)
{
    if ((NULL == s1) ||
        (NULL == s2)) {
        return false;
    }

    int static const
    _capacity = 256;    // Assumption
    int
    charNums[_capacity] = {0};
    char
    *cRef1 = s1,
    *cRef2 = s2;
    while ('\0' != *cRef1 && '\0' != *cRef2) {
        charNums[*cRef1] += 1;
        charNums[*cRef2] -= 1;
        cRef1++;
        cRef2++;
    }

    if ('\0' != *cRef1 || '\0'  != *cRef2) {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < _capacity; i++) {
        if (0 != charNums[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create two methods:

**1. First method takes a string and returns a sorted string:**

`public String sort(String str) {
           char char_set[] = str.toCharArray();
           Arrays.sort(char_set);
           return new String(char_set);
       }`

**2. Second method takes two strings and return a boolean:**

```
   `public boolean sort(String x, String y) {
       if (x.length() != y.length()) {
           System.out.println("false");
           return false;
       }
       System.out.println(sort(x).equals(sort(y)));
       return sort(x).equals(sort(y));
   }`
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by using a Dictionary in C#. A basic implementation is like :

```
    private static bool IsPermutation(string str1, string str2)
    {
        if (str1.Length != str2.Length)
            return false;

        var dictionary = new Dictionary<char, int>();

        foreach(var x in str1)
        {
            if (dictionary.ContainsKey(x))
                dictionary[x] += 1;
            else
                dictionary.Add(x, 1);
        }

        foreach (var y in str2)
        {
            if (dictionary.ContainsKey(y))
            {
                if (dictionary[y] > 0)
                    dictionary[y] -= 1;
                else
                    return false;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }

        foreach(var el in dictionary)
        {
            if (el.Value != 0)
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Time Complexity is O(n), linear solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static boolean isPermutation(String s1, String s2) {
    if (s1.length() != s2.length()) {
        return false;
    }else if(s1.length()==0 ){
        return true;
    }
    else if(s1.length()==1){
        return s1.equals(s2);
    }
    char[] s = s1.toCharArray();
    char[] t = s2.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < t.length; j++) {

            if (s.length == s1.length() && (i == 0 && j == t.length - 1) && s[i] != t[j]) {
                return false;
            }
            if (s[i] == t[j]) {
                String ss = new String(s);
                String tt = new String(t);
                s = (ss.substring(0, i) + ss.substring(i + 1, s.length)).toCharArray();
                t = (tt.substring(0, j) + tt.substring(j + 1, t.length)).toCharArray();

                System.out.println(new String(s));
                System.out.println(new String(t));

                i = 0;
                j = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return s[0]==t[0] ;
}
```

This solution works for any charset. With an O(n) complexity.

The output for: `isPermutation("The Big Bang Theory", "B B T Tehgiangyroeh")`

```
he Big Bang Theory
B B  Tehgiangyroeh
e Big Bang Theory
B B  Tegiangyroeh
 Big Bang Theory
B B  Tgiangyroeh
Big Bang Theory
BB  Tgiangyroeh
ig Bang Theory
B  Tgiangyroeh
g Bang Theory
B  Tgangyroeh
 Bang Theory
B  Tangyroeh
Bang Theory
B Tangyroeh
Bng Theory
B Tngyroeh
Bg Theory
B Tgyroeh
B Theory
B Tyroeh
BTheory
BTyroeh
Bheory
Byroeh
Beory
Byroe
Bory
Byro
Bry
Byr
By
By
B
B
true
```

Answer (score 0):

Best Way to do this is by sorting the two strings first and then compare them. It's not the most efficient way but it's clean and is bound to the runtime of the sorting routine been used.

```
boolean arePermutation(String s1, String s2) { 
  if(s1.lenght() != s2.lenght()) {
     return false;
   }
   return mySort(s1).equals(mySort(s2));
 }

  String mySort(String s) {
   Char letters[] = s.toCharArray();
   Arrays.sort(letters);
   return new String(letters);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String str= "abcd";
    String str1 ="dcazb";
    int count=0;

    char s[]= str.toCharArray();
    char s1[]= str1.toCharArray();

    for(char c:s)
    {
        count = count+(int)c ;
    }

    for(char c1:s1)
    {
        count=count-(int)c1;

    }

    if(count==0)
    System.out.println("String are Anagram");
    else
    System.out.println("String are not Anagram");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple program I wrote that gives the answer in O(n) for time complexity and O(1) for space complexity. It works by mapping every character to a prime number and then multiplying together all of the characters in the string's prime mappings together. If the two strings are permutations then they should have the same unique characters each with the same number of occurrences.

Here is some sample code that accomplishes this:

```
// maps keys to a corresponding unique prime
static Map<Integer, Integer> primes = generatePrimes(255); // use 255 for
                                                            // ASCII or the
                                                            // number of
                                                            // possible
                                                            // characters

public static boolean permutations(String s1, String s2) {
    // both strings must be same length
    if (s1.length() != s2.length())
        return false;

    // the corresponding primes for every char in both strings are multiplied together
    int s1Product = 1;
    int s2Product = 1;

    for (char c : s1.toCharArray())
        s1Product *= primes.get((int) c);

    for (char c : s2.toCharArray())
        s2Product *= primes.get((int) c);

    return s1Product == s2Product;

}

private static Map<Integer, Integer> generatePrimes(int n) {

    Map<Integer, Integer> primes = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    primes.put(0, 2);

    for (int i = 2; primes.size() < n; i++) {
        boolean divisible = false;

        for (int v : primes.values()) {
            if (i % v == 0) {
                divisible = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!divisible) {
            primes.put(primes.size(), i);
            System.out.println(i + " ");
        }
    }

    return primes;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment on this solution, https://stackoverflow.com/a/31709645/697935 here's that approach, revised.

```
private static boolean is_permutation(String s1, String s2) {
    HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    int count = 1;
    if(s1.length()!=s2.length()) {
        return false;
    }
    for(Character c: s1.toCharArray()) {
        if(!map.containsKey(c)) {
            map.put(c, 1);
        }
        else {
            map.put(c, map.get(c) + 1);
        }
    }
    for(Character c: s2.toCharArray()) {
        if(!map.containsKey(c)) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            map.put(c, map.get(c) - 1);
        }
    }
    for(Character c: map.keySet()) {
        if(map.get(c) != 0) { return false; }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool is_permutation1(string str1, string str2) {
    sort(str1.begin(), str1.end());
    sort(str2.begin(), str2.end());
    for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) {    
        if (str1[i] != str2[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Though this answer might solve the issue the OP experienced, it is always better to add an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to give a **recursive solution** for this problem as I did not find any answer which was recursive. I think that this code seems to be tough but if you'll try to understand it you'll see the beauty of this code. Recursion is sometimes hard to understand but good to use! This method returns all the permutations of the entered String 's' and keeps storing them in the array 'arr[]'. The value of 't' initially is blank "" .

```
import java.io.*;
class permute_compare2str
{
    static String[] arr= new String [1200];
    static int p=0;
    void permutation(String s,String t)
    {
        if (s.length()==0)
        {
            arr[p++]=t;
            return;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
            permutation(s.substring(0,i)+s.substring(i+1),t+s.charAt(i));
    }
    public static void main(String kr[])throws IOException
    {
        int flag = 0;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter the first String:");
        String str1 = br.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the second String:");
        String str2 = br.readLine();
        new permute_compare2str().permutation(str1,"");
        for(int i = 0; i < p; ++i)
        {
            if(arr[i].equals(str2))
            {
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(flag == 1)
            System.out.println("True");
        else
        {
            System.out.println("False");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

One **limitation** that I can see is that the *length of the array is fixed* and so will not be able to return values for a large String value 's'. Please alter the same as per the requirements. There are other solutions to this problem as well.

I have shared this code because you can actually use this to get the permutations of a string printed directly without the array as well.

HERE:

```
void permutations(String s, String t)
    {
        if (s.length()==0)
        {
            System.out.print(t+" ");
            return;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
            permutations(s.substring(0,i)+s.substring(i+1),t+s.charAt(i));
    }
```

Value of 's' is the string whose permutations is needed and value of 't' is again empty "".

Reference: [Introduction to Programming in Java](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/Permutations.java.html)

Answer (score 0):

Linear Time Solution using just one HashMap.

```
public static boolean check( String string1, String string2 ){
        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    if( string1.length() != string2.length()){
        return false;
    }

    for( int i=0; i<string1.length(); i++ ){
        if( map.containsKey( String.valueOf( string1.charAt(i)))){
            map.put( String.valueOf( string1.charAt(i)), map.get( String.valueOf( string1.charAt(i)) ) + 1 );
        }else{
            map.put( String.valueOf( string1.charAt(i)), 1 );
        }
    }

    for( int i=0; i<string2.length(); i++ ){
        if( map.containsKey( String.valueOf( string2.charAt(i)))){
            map.put( String.valueOf( string2.charAt(i)), map.get( String.valueOf( string2.charAt(i))) - 1);
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry: map.entrySet()){
        if( entry.getValue() != 0 ){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Time complexity : O(n)

```
public static boolean isPermutation(String str1, String str2) {
    if (str1.length() != str2.length()) {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) {
        char ch = str1.charAt(i);

        if (str2.indexOf(ch) == -1) 
            return false;
        else
            str2 = str2.replaceFirst(String.valueOf(ch), " ");
    }

    return true;
}
```

TestCase

```
@Test
public void testIsPernutationTrue() {
    assertTrue(Permutation.isPermutation("abc", "cba"));
    assertTrue(Permutation.isPermutation("geeksforgeeks", "forgeeksgeeks"));
    assertTrue(Permutation.isPermutation("anagram", "margana"));
}

@Test
public void testIsPernutationFalse() {
    assertFalse(Permutation.isPermutation("abc", "caa"));
    assertFalse(Permutation.isPermutation("anagramm", "marganaa"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Thought Process

- Two Pointers
- Scanning left to right with sliding window
- When all the characters from s1 are used up, we have to make sure the sliding window is exactly the length of s1
- Time complexity O(n)

### Solution:

```java
class Solution {
    public boolean checkInclusion(String s1, String s2) {
        int[] map = new int[128];
        for (char c : s1.toCharArray()) {
            map[c]++;
        }
        int count = s1.length();
        char[] chars = s2.toCharArray();
        int left = 0, right = 0;
        while (right < chars.length) {
            if (map[chars[right++]]-- > 0) count--;
            while (count == 0) {
                if (right - left == s1.length()) return true;
                if (++map[chars[left++]] > 0) count++;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In JS you can do something like this...

```
const isPermutation = (str1,str2) => {
  let arr1 = str1.split('').sort().join('');
  let arr2 = str2.split('').sort().join('');
  return arr1 === arr2;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I did this in C if anyone cares.  It assumes ASCII values and uses the characters ordinal value:

```
bool is_permutation(const char *a, const char *b)
{                                                
    if (a == NULL || b == NULL)              
            return false;                    

    if (strlen(a) != strlen(b))              
            return false;                    

    int sum_a = 0, sum_b = 0;                

    while (*a != '\0')                       
            sum_a += (int)*a++;              

    while (*b != '\0')                       
            sum_b += (int)*b++;              

    return (sum_a == sum_b);                 
}
```

Comment: This would fail I guess. As there can be 2 different string summing upto the same number.

Comment: please provide an example of where this will fail.

Answer (score -1):

Using properties of XOR (Identity, Commutative, and Self-Inverse). Complexity: `O(N)`, programming language C#

```
  static bool IsPerm(string word, string targetWord){

    if(word.Length != targetWord.Length){
      return false;
    }

    var xorProduct = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < word.Length; i++){ // O(N)
      xorProduct ^= word[i] ^ targetWord[i];
    }

    return xorProduct == 0;
  }
```