# Make sure that two strings are composed of the same letters in different orders

Tags: java, string

I have to create a Java program that returns `true` if two strings are composed by the same letters like `"EMS"` and `"MES"`, or `false` if it is not the case.

I tried to develop some code and I finally found a solution but It only works for words which have all letters different (no letters duplicated) It doesn't work for `"EEM"` and `"EMS"`.

```
String mot = "EMS", word="EES";
char[] tab= mot.toCharArray();
char[] vect= word.toCharArray();
int i = mot.length(), j = word.length(), a = 0;      
if (i != j)
    System.out.println("false");
else {
    for (int k=0; k<i; k++) {
        for (int l=0; l<i; l++) {
            if (tab[k] == vect[l])
                a++; 
        }
    }
    if (a == i)
         System.out.println("true");
    else
         System.out.println("false");
}
```

Comment: it's so easy to google it
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985328/checking-if-2-strings-contain-the-same-characters

Comment: Sort the two `String`s are then do a simple comparison (even convert them back to `String`s and use `equals`)...

Comment: Uhm, well, `EEM` and `EMS` do not have the same letters indeed; so the output is pretty much expected, right?

Comment: @fge: When he said it doesn't work, I believe he meant the code incorrectly returns `true` for those two strings.

Comment: Hello, yes i meant it returns true for those two strings I posted the case where this code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible idea to use indexOf() to locate matching chars in each string...

```
public static boolean sameChars(String str1, String str2){

    for(int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++){
        if(str2.indexOf(str1.charAt(i)) == -1)
            return false;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < str2.length(); i++){
        if(str1.indexOf(str2.charAt(i)) == -1)
            return false;
    }
    return true;

}
```

Comment: Just took a look at @user3137043's link. Apparently there was a similar idea there too. :-)

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
new HashSet<Character>(Arrays.asList("EMS".toCharArray())
  .equals(new HashSet<Character>(Arrays.asList("MES".toCharArray()));
```

Comment: This does not properly take the case of duplicate letters into account (which was specifically pointed out as a flaw of the original implementation)

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the false positive result is that you're comparing the `E` in `EMS` to *both* of the `E`s in `EES`.  You need to get rid of that inner `for` loop. You also need to sort the arrays before you compare them, as one of the commenters [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28467022/make-sure-that-too-strings-are-composed-by-the-same-letters-with-different-order#comment45259706_28467022).

I won't provide code to demonstrate because it's such basic-level stuff.  If this isn't a homework problem, it should be. :D

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I wanted to add that I'am new to java so I'am doing my best to get the basics