# check if two strings are permutation of each other?

Tags: java

I am solving this question as an assignment of the school. But the two of my test cases are coming out wrong when I submit the code? I don't know what went wrong. I have checked various other test cases and corner cases and it all coming out right.

**Here is my code:**

```
    public static boolean isPermutation(String input1, String input2) {

       if(input1.length() != input2.length())
       {
           return false;
       }

       int index1 =0;
       int index2 =0;
       int count=0;


       while(index2<input2.length())
       {

           while(index1<input1.length())
           {
               if( input1.charAt(index1)==input2.charAt(index2) )
               {
                   index1=0;
                   count++;
                   break;
               }
             index1++;     

           }
           index2++;
       }


       if(count==input1.length())
       {
           return true;
       }


       return false;

}
```

**SAMPLE INPUT**

```
abcde
baedc
```

**output**

```
true
```

**SAMPLE INPUT**

```
abc
cbd
```

**output**

```
false
```

Comment: can you add the input , expected output and your output please?

Comment: what are your test cases?

Comment: What are the 2 test cases?

Comment: Are "aab" and "ab" permutations of each other ? And "aab" and "abb" ?

Comment: You could just sort the two strings and compare their sorted forms.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking if two strings are permutations of each other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131997/checking-if-two-strings-are-permutations-of-each-other)

Comment: Well, and "aab" and "abb". This algorithm is flawed.

Comment: You are only checking them have the same letters, not the same number of letters.

Comment: both of your test cases are passing. what's the problem?

Comment: @DenysSéguret no they are not I have checked it using custom input and the expected output of the tool is giving false and so is mine

Comment: @mc20 these are just sample test cases the actual testcases are not revealed by them

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A simpler solution would be to sort the characters in both strings and compare those character arrays.

- [`String.toCharArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) returns an array of characters from a String
- [`Arrays.sort(char \[\])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28char[]%29) to sort a character array
- [`Arrays.equals(char \[\], char \[\])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28char[],%20char[]%29) to compare the arrays

Example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(isPermutation("hello", "olleh"));
    System.out.println(isPermutation("hell", "leh"));
    System.out.println(isPermutation("world", "wdolr"));
}

private static boolean isPermutation(String a, String b) {
    char [] aArray = a.toCharArray();
    char [] bArray = b.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(aArray);
    Arrays.sort(bArray);
    return Arrays.equals(aArray, bArray);
}
```

A more long-winded solution without sorting would to be check every character in A is also in B

```
private static boolean isPermutation(String a, String b) {
    char[] aArray = a.toCharArray();
    char[] bArray = b.toCharArray();

    if (a.length() != b.length()) {
        return false;
    }
    int found = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < aArray.length; i++) {
        char eachA = aArray[i];
        // check each character in A is found in B
        for (int k = 0; k < bArray.length; k++) {
            if (eachA == bArray[k]) {
                found++;
                bArray[k] = '\uFFFF'; // clear so we don't find again
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return found == a.length();
}
```

Comment: Personally I'd take a size check first, then check if the "sum" of the characters was equal. Then do your bit.

Comment: Possibly in extremely high performance situations, but sounds like premature optimisation to me... Just looking at source of Arrays.equals(), this is one of the first checks anyway...

Comment: That's interesting. Perhaps I'm old-fashioned in thinking that sorting is always a bottleneck. (P.S. consider checking for `null`).

Comment: @Adam your solution got all the testcases right, but I still don't figure out what is wrong with the solution of mine :p. Can you tell?

Comment: @PVP Counting the characters is not good enough... if you have the same character multiple times in first string but not second, e.g. aab and abb... then your algorithm will count 3, but really a is only in the 2nd string once... I get around this my removing the character when it is found so it cannot be found again

Comment: @Adam sir can you give me a test case which will give wrong output using the code that I have.

Comment: Yes, try "aab" and "abb", your code returns true because of the reasons I've tried to explain above...

Comment: @Adam your solution is excellent but I can't help thinking about the unlikely case of an input string containing a nul character which would make it go wrong. Perhaps you could use '\uFFFF' instead, which is a Unicode not-a-character, i.e. guaranteed by the Unicode standard not to be part of any valid piece of text, or simply remove the character by shifting the remaining characters to the left (not as badly performing as you might imagine, since it means the next parse will have one less character in bArray to go through.)

Answer (score 2):

You have two ways to proceed

1. Sort both strings and then compare both strings
2. Count the characters in string and then match.

Follow the tutorial [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-whether-two-strings-are-anagram-of-each-other/)

Answer (score 1):

In case you String is ASCII you may use the next approach:

1. Create 256 elements int array
2. Increment element of corresponding character whenever it's found in `string1`
3. Decrement element of corresponding character whenever it's found in `string2`
4. If all elements are `0`, then `string2` is permutation of `string1`

Overall complexity of this approach is `O(n)`. The only drawback is space allocation for `charCount` array:

```
public static boolean isPermutation(String s1, String s2) {
    if (s1.length() != s2.length()) {
        return false;
    }
    int[] charCount = new int[256];
    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
        charCount[s1.charAt(i)]++;
        charCount[s2.charAt(i)]--;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < charCount.length; i++) {
        if (charCount[i] != 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

If your strings can hold non-ASCII values, the same approach could be implemented using `HashMap<String, Integer>` as character count storage

Answer (score 1):

I have a recursive method to solve the permutations problem. I think that this code will seem to be tough but if you will try to understand it you will see the beauty of this code. Recursion is always hard to understand but good to use! This method returns all the permutations of the entered String 's' and keeps storing them in the array 'arr[]'. The value of 't' initially is blank "" .

```
import java.io.*;
class permute_compare2str
{
    static String[] arr= new String [1200];
    static int p=0;
    void permutation(String s,String t)
    {
        if (s.length()==0)
        {
            arr[p++]=t;
            return;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
            permutation(s.substring(0,i)+s.substring(i+1),t+s.charAt(i));
    }
    public static void main(String kr[])throws IOException
    {
        int flag = 0;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter the first String:");
        String str1 = br.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the second String:");
        String str2 = br.readLine();
        new permute_compare2str().permutation(str1,"");
        for(int i = 0; i < p; ++i)
        {
            if(arr[i].equals(str2))
            {
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(flag == 1)
            System.out.println("True");
        else
        {
            System.out.println("False");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

One limitation that I can see is that the length of the array is fixed and so will not be able to return values for a large String value 's'. Please alter the same as per the requirements. There are other solution to this problem as well.

I have shared this code because you can actually use this to get the permutations of a string printed directly without the array as well.

HERE:

```
void permutations(String s,String t)
    {
        if (s.length()==0)
        {
            System.out.print(t+" ");
            return;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
            permutations(s.substring(0,i)+s.substring(i+1),t+s.charAt(i));
    }
```

Value of 's' is the string whose permutations is needed and value of 't' is again empty "".

Answer (score 0):

it will take O(n log n) cuz i sort each string and i used more space to store each one

```
public static boolean checkPermutation(String a,String b){
    return sortString(a).equals(sortString(b));
}
private static String sortString(String test) {
    char[] tempChar = test.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(tempChar);
    return new String(tempChar);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       String checkPermutation(String a,String b){
         char[] aArr = a.toCharArray();
         char[] bArr = b.toCharArray();
         Arrays.sort(aArr);
         Arrays.sort(bArr);

         if(aArr.length != bArr.length){
            return "NO";
          }
         int p = 0, q = 0;
         while(p < aArr.length){
           if(aArr[p] != bArr[q]){
              return "NO";
           }
            p++;
            q++;
         }
         return "YES";
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean isStringArePermutate(String s1, String s2){
    if(s1==null || s2==null) {
        return false;
    }
    
    int len1 = s1.length();
    int len2 =s2.length();
    

    if(len1!=len2){
        return false;
    }
    for(int i =0;i<len1;i++){
        if(!s1.contains(String.valueOf(s2.charAt(i)))) {
            return false;
        }
        s1=s1.replaceFirst(String.valueOf(s2.charAt(i)), "");
    }   

    if(s1.equals("")) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation.