# Finding a permutation of one string in another: Xor solution strange behavior

Tags: python, algorithm, xor, bitwise-xor

I am working on the following problem:

[image]

I was inspired by [the first answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131997/checking-if-two-strings-are-permutations-of-each-other) to come up with a solution that utilizes some of the properties of XOR (Identity, Commutative, and Self-Inverse) to work in O(n) time and O(1) space.

```
def checkInclusion(s1: str, s2: str) -> bool:
    # Checks for permutation of s1 inside of s2.
    # Xor's all of the characters in a s1-length window of s2
    # If xor_product = 0 --> permutation identified
    # Relies on properties of xor to find answer: identity, communtative, and self-inverse
    xor_product = 0
    for i in range(0, len(s2) - len(s1) + 1):
        s1_index = 0
        for j in range(i, i + len(s1)):
            xor_product = xor_product ^ ord(s1[s1_index]) ^ ord(s2[j])
            s1_index += 1
        if xor_product == 0: return True
        xor_product = 0
    return False
```

This solution works for most inputs, but fails when `s1 = "kitten"` and `s2 = "sitting"`. Is this solution conceptually flawed? If so, then how? If not, then what's the bug?
I'm admittedly new to coding interview style questions. All help appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried debugging yet? What where your findings?

Comment: @MrSmith42 Yes. The problem persists in spite of everything I've tried. I strongly suspected that the xor approach was conceptually flawed but I wanted to understand why. Unless if I were to use a more sophisticated hashing method, I guess there is no way to do this in O(1) space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, xor-approach is flawed.

It is kind of simple hash, but this hash might be indentical for different strings (consider 6^7=1 and 3^2=1). In case of xor hash coincidence you need to check real similarity with other means - for example, with direct comparison of sorted string and substring, but this way is not appropriate for contest case -  special tests with multiple identical hashes will cause slow work, the worst case time is too large.

Instead you can exploit approach with dictionary/counter. Update counters for every new item and for item leaving sliding window and check that all entries of counter have the same counts as sample.

P.S. Keeping `NumberOfGoodCounters` value helps to avoid checking of all counters at every step.